# When l renamed layouts/admin.blade.php I got layouts.app ref error

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Making adminarea in Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 / tailwindcss: 2.2 app
I renamed file.

```
resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
```

into

```
resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php
```

and fixed in View/Components/AppLayout.php :

```
public function render()
{
    return view('layouts.admin');
}
```

and run commands :

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan  clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload
```

but I still got error :

```
View [layouts.app] not found. (View: /Project/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Macros/livewire-view-component.blade.php)
```

Looks like there is some default "app" ref, which raise this error?
Which is valid way t5o split my app into several layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: This may help you. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components

Comment: Thanks!
specifying layout for any component could be a decision
I see also 
'layout' => 'app.other_default_layout'
in which file have I to edit these options ?

Comment: in the config/livewire.php file